# Flash drive lsblk says 0B

Tags: filesystem, usb-drive

A friend asked for help with this USB stick, which we can't open. Ubuntu won't auto mount the USB, and this is the output of the lsblk command.
We are trying to recover the pictures of his son, that should be in there.
Can you guys help us?

[lsblk output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CaaGB.png)

Comment: There is a "controller" inside the USB-stick; based on the fact that you got "0B" in lsblk output I'd wager the controller is "dead". Have you tried `disks` (gnome-disks from shell) or `sudo fldisk -l` to see if either of those tells more.

Comment: You can analyze the problem according to [this link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/144852/cant-format-my-usb-drive-i-have-already-tried-with-mkdosfs-and-gparted/933035#933035) and if you are lucky, find a solution.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.